# Navbar exceeding viewport only in mobile live server

Tags: html, css, react-bootstrap, nav

I'm experiencing this strange behaviour in my webpage https://vinoreo.mx .

**The navbar is exceeding the viewport in mobile - live server. Localhost works fine.**

It happens only in the `"/"` route, the other routes show correctly the viewport.

Before loading all DOM elements the viewport shows correctly, but once the elements update (react front-end) this is when the problem appears.

The `SPA` uses this `meta` tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Live mobile view using iPhone 6/7/8 Plus as reference

[image: live-view]

Localhost view using same iPhone 6/7/8 Plus as reference

[image: localhost-view]

As you can see `footer navbar` simply disappears and also the whatsapp and cart buttons which are also fixed, and come from the main top `navbar`.

I have reviewed my `style.scss` file and I have not messed with `navbar` class `widths`.

```
.navbar {
    padding: 0.5rem 10%;
}

@media (max-width: 991.98px) {
    .navbar {
        padding: 2% 2%;
    }
}
.nav-link {
    padding: 0px;
}

.navbar-text {
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

I'm using `React-bootstrap` classes which I believe are the regular bootstrap ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me some days and several attempts on moving css and finally solved it by adding this to `meta content` tag:

> initial-scale=1,minimum-scale=1